# if fopen doesn't exist, it doesn't change the header to 404?

Tags: php, fopen

Fopen works, I can read the files and stuff but when I specify an invalid one I want it to return a 404 header but it's not working exactly.

```
$handle = fopen($filepath, "rb");

if (!$handle) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
```

In about 5 posts I've read here, these are the examples and they look the same to me.

Comment: See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) for how to do it

Comment: I think we are missing some code that will reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you want

```
$handle = fopen($filepath, "rb");

if ($handle === false) {
   http_response_code(404);
   exit;
}
```

It sets the response code when you are unable to open the file (as per the manual pages)

Comment: Why do you need a strict comparison? Any successful value of `$handle` will be truthy.

Comment: Just being pedantic I suppose

Comment: An answer is supposed to fix the problem, not just show a different way to do it. If his original code doesn't work, there's no reason to expect this to work better, is there?

Answer (score 1):

So, since this topic is getting big I didn't realize I'd get so many responses. Thank you all!

So, the issue actually wasn't the code I had... I was literally stupid, it was giving me a 404 Not Found this whole time but it didn't seem like it for some reason. Protip, don't turn Error reporting off and have an alternative PHP function surpress errors & headers.

Thanks all, but there was actually no error in the code, just my pure stupidity.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer, since it doesn't provide any useful information for future readers about how to solve the problem. Since the question doesn't have any upvoted answers, I think you may be able to delete it. If not, flag it for the moderators to close it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Problem: When you did **$handle = fopen($filepath, "rb");** PHP's fopen tries to locate the File. Failing to locate the File, it generates an Error which resulted in some Output being sent to the Stream. With Output already sent to the Stream; it is not anymore possible to send a header... so ***an IF-ELSE Statement could do the Trick***:

```
    <?php


        $filepath = "page-1.php";

        if(file_exists($filepath) && ($handle = @fopen($filepath, "rb"))){
            // WORK WITH YOUR $handle  IN THIS BLOCK
        }else{
            header("location: page-2.php"); // YOU SHOULD REDIRECT TO A LOCATION SENDING IT THE HEADER...
            //header("location: page-1.php"); // SENDING TO THE SAME LOCATION WORKS AS WELL...
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried this out? BTW - What raises an exception in this code? Also a file can exist but you may not be able to read it!

Comment: @Ed Heal    About the Try-Catch: perhaps not necessary... now gone... ***maybe you should try it out, and enlighten us more...*** over here it was tried ***;-)***

Comment: @Poiz You can't use both `Location` and `404` headers.

Comment: `Location` sends a `301` response code, that conflicts with trying to send a `404` response.

Comment: @EdHeal But did you now test it out... ***at least to enlighten us a little more?*** Does it return the said **404 Error**?

Comment: @Barmar - Will the 404 overrule toe 301 (as it occurs afterwards)

Comment: I'm not sure which will take precedence, but my guess is the last one. I'm not sure why he put the redirect into the answer, since the question clearly wants a 404 error rather than a redirect.

Comment: @Barmar        ***Poiz You can't use both Location and 404 headers.***  OK... **Humans also can't fly on an object too until after the failure of Da Vinci, The Wright Brothers tried it out and said:** ***YES! WE CAN!!!*** Rules are meant to keep you on track, once on track, where are the Rules? Try it yourself... how does it work???